# How to fix "Wordpress "wp-admin/includes/file.php" Error code - 500

Tags: php, wordpress, file

I'm setting up a multiple file upload in WordPress fronted side.
I follow this "http://www.kvcodes.com/2013/12/create-front-end-multiple-file-upload-wordpress/" 
I get a error code 500 while add

```
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
```

This.

While I add this

```
require_once('../../../wp-admin/includes/image.php');
require_once('../../../wp-admin/includes/file.php');
require_once('../../../wp-admin/includes/media.php');
```

"
Only get error -500 in file.php

My Code:

```
if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']  ) {
if ( $_FILES ) { 
        $files = $_FILES["kv_multiple_attachments"];  
        foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $value) {            
                if ($files['name'][$key]) {
                    $file = array( 
                        'name' => $files['name'][$key],
                        'type' => $files['type'][$key], 
                        'tmp_name' => $files['tmp_name'][$key], 
                        'error' => $files['error'][$key],
                        'size' => $files['size'][$key]
                    ); 
                     $_FILES = array ("kv_multiple_attachments" => $file); 
                    //var_dump($_FILES);
                    foreach ($_FILES as $file => $key) {
                        $pid = "1";
                        $newupload = kv_handle_attachment($file,$pid); 
                    }
                } 
            } 
        }

}
function kv_handle_attachment($file_handler,$post_id,$set_thu=false) {
    // check to make sure its a successful upload
    if ($_FILES[$file_handler]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) __return_false();
//echo "ss";
    require_once('../../../wp-admin/includes/image.php');
    require_once('../../../wp-admin/includes/file.php');
    require_once('../../../wp-admin/includes/media.php');
echo "ss";
    $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file_handler, $post_id );

         // If you want to set a featured image frmo your uploads. 
    if ($set_thu) set_post_thumbnail($post_id, $attach_id);
    return $attach_id;
}
```

Comment: Error 500 means look into the error.log for the real error. And relative path references are relative to the current working directory (invocation script), not an a per file basis.

Comment: Thanks @mario I will Check my error log.